# How to create 5 digit sequence number

Tags: php

I am having trouble when generate 5 digit sequence number in PHP.
All I want it when the user call the PHP file it will generate 00001 and then the next call it will generate 00002 and so on.
And then for the next day it will regenerate 00001, 00002 and so on.
eg: for today, I want to generate the sequence 5 digit number from 00001 to 99999 and for tomorrow I want to re-generate the sequence 5 digit number like yesterday.

Comment: 5 digit sequence number means?? 12345 not 25631???

Comment: First of all a number never start with `0` you may be looking for string..

Comment: Store the number somewhere, then fetch and increase it every time the page is called. There are literally dozens of feasible ways you can do this.

Comment: @RivnatNasah Yes bro, sequence number 1, 2, 3 with leading "0"

Comment: How much number you want?? 10, 20, 30....

Comment: @RivnatNasah I want to 00001 ..... to 99999, but want to refresh to 00001 for next day

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) for this:

```
$num = 1;
echo sprintf("%'.05d\n", $num);
```

But ultimately, this would be a string. Not a number. With the above code, what happens is, when you send the number, say:

```
for ($num = 1; $num <= 50; $num++)
    echo sprintf("%'.05d\n", $num);
```

The above will give you:

```
00001  // type: String. Use intval() to get the integral value.
00002  // type: String. Use intval() to get the integral value.
00003  // type: String. Use intval() to get the integral value.
```

And so on. The good thing is, use a function like, `getSequence()`:

```
function getSequence($num) {
  return sprintf("%'.05d\n", $num);
}
```

And call the function on the number:

```
$num = 756;
getSequence($num); // 00756
```

**Output**

```
00001
00002
00003
00004
00005
00006
00007
00008
00009
00010
00011
00012
00013
00014
00015
00016
00017
00018
00019
00020
00021
00022
00023
00024
00025
00026
00027
00028
00029
00030
00031
00032
00033
00034
00035
00036
00037
00038
00039
00040
00041
00042
00043
00044
00045
00046
00047
00048
00049
00050
```

**Fiddle: https://ideone.com/4MpnZe**

---

**Update:** The OP wants us to write code. But here it goes.

To answer your question, you need a server side counter for the date. Let's say, today's date can be got by:

```
date("Ymd", strtotime("now")); // 20160608
```

Let's do this:

```
$today = date("Ymd", strtotime("now"));
// Check if there's a file with the name exists:
if (file_exists($today)) {
  // Nothing to do. :)
} else {
  file_put_contents($today, 0);
}
$count = file_get_contents($today);
$count++;
echo sprintf("%'.05d\n", $count);
```

This will get the count for the day, every day, and the next day, it starts with `1`.

Comment: yes bro PK, thanks for your answer. Your code is generating all the number at once. I don't want to generate all the number at once. I want for the first time it will generate 00001 and for the second time it will generate 00002 and so on. and get back to 00001 in the next day. Can you help me how to do? Thanks

Comment: @tontonlayxx You need to clarify the question... `:)` That looks like a big one...

Comment: well, you need some sort of database or a simple file where you're going to save the last number generated, so you can increment it next time.

Comment: @OliverMaksimovic bro it will be the right answer for my requirement but I am still confusing

Comment: @tontonlayxx Check my answer. `:D` See the bottom update.

Answer (score 0):

Got you, you need to store the value in database / file, and with the day chagne just reset the database / file.

```
$i = readFromDBorFile();
$num = sprintf("%'.05d&nbsp;", $i++);
```

Comment: Sorry? What? I don't understand.

Comment: Oops, it was you, I thought the OP. Almost same answer.... I can make it before you but i just trying to make some clearance from the OP, but in the mean time you did it.

Comment: I saw your rep. 88k+ so i thought you are right what i think so i also make another answer.

Comment: Buddy, I don't think creating another answer is good. Check my answer again and see what do you think? Your feedback is appreciated. :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the counter somehow for the next request to not return the same number. Simplest solution would be to save it to a local file.

Try this:

```
// let's store the file name
$filename = 'counter.txt';

// create the file if it doesn't exist
if (!file_exists($filename)) {
    $counter_file = fopen($filename, "w");
    fwrite($counter_file, "0");
    $counter = 0
} else {
    $counter_file = fopen($filename, "r");

    // will read the first line
    $counter = fgets($counter_file)
}

// increase $counter
$counter++;

// echo counter
echo $counter

// save the increased counter
fwrite($counter_file, "0");

// close the file
fclose($counter_file);
```

Comment: `file_**t_contents` is better. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar you are right, your answer is shorter and better.

Comment: @PraveenKumar and Martin Gottweis first thanks for your answer and second sorry for late response. I read two of your code and make small changes and got solution. Here my code

    date("Ymd", strtotime("now")); 
$today = date("Ymd", strtotime("now")) . '.txt';
if (file_exists($today)) {
  
} else {
  file_put_contents($today, 0);
}
$count = file_get_contents($today);
$add = $count++;
$transID = sprintf("%'.05d\n", $count);
$counter_file = fopen($today, "w");
fwrite($counter_file, $count++);
echo $transID;
fclose($counter_file);

Answer (score 0):

/* create sequence number with 4 digits
        Nb the file must be created first 
    */

```
function sequence(){
    $letter = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];

    $content = file_get_contents("seq_file");
    $content = file_get_contents("seq_file") + 1 ;
    $letter_number = file_get_contents("letter_number");

    if ($content ==9999){

        file_put_contents("seq_file",0);
        $content = 0 ;
        $letter_number = $letter_number + 1 ;
        file_put_contents("letter_number",$letter_number);
    }
    file_put_contents("seq_file",$content);

       return sprintf("%s-%04d",$letter[$letter_number],$content); // A-0252
} // end of function sequence()



if(file_exists("seq_file") &&  file_exists("letter_number")){
    echo sequence();
} else {
    file_put_contents("letter_number",0);
    file_put_contents("seq_file",0);
    echo sequence();

}
```

Comment: sequence number containing letter like A-0252.the benefit of this script is that each sequence starting  with a letter will be associated will a maximum number  of 9999